# "ti sdk list" isn't displaying latest release(s)

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I'm having issues updating my Titanium SDK.
If I use the command `ti sdk list -r` I get this list:

```
Releases:
   4.0.0.GA [installed] [latest]
   3.5.1.GA
   3.5.0.GA
   3.4.1.GA
   3.4.0.GA
   3.3.0.GA
   3.2.3.GA
   ...
```

I'm sure that there are more recent versions than 4.0.0.GA. 
Reading the official wiki for example, I can see that latest release is 5.2.0.

Any help please? How do I update the SDK?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must update your SDK version, you can follow the steps described in the    Appcelerator Blog post [GA Release of CLI 5.2, Titanium 5.2 and Studio 4.5](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/02/ga-release-of-cli-5-2-titanium-5-2-and-studio-4-5/):

```
$ [sudo] npm install -g appcelerator
$ appc setup
```

then

```
$ [sudo] npm install -g titanium alloy
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved my issue. It is a bit strange that you have to login to appcelerator.com to download the latest sdk, isn't it? -.-

Comment: the open source version doesn't offer the latest builds. Titanium/ti is open source, Appc CLI not

Comment: The OSS CLI is supposed to get you the second last SDK. Now as you see, that is not the case at the moment with 5.2.0.GA out already. We will update this soon.

Comment: Ah thank you then. I'm interested in using the OSS CLI version, so I've uninstalled "appc" and I'm just using "ti". Thanks.